# Can't bind to 'dataSource' since it isn't a known property of 'table' still seems to be a problem

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have looked at all the reason this is happening online and I still cannot resolve the above error on 'DataSource', can anyone see anything wrong in my code?

HTML:

```
    <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">

  <ng-container matColumnDef="position">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>No.</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.position }}</td>
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns"></tr>
</table>
```

TS:

```
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';

export interface PeriodicElement {
  position: number;
}

const ELEMENT_DATA: PeriodicElement[] = [
  { position: 1 },
  { position: 2 },
  { position: 3 },
];

/**
 * @title Basic use of `<table mat-table>`
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'app-component',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
})
export class AppComponent {
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['position'];
  dataSource = ELEMENT_DATA;
}
```

Module:

```
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { MatTableModule, MatSortModule } from '@angular/material';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [BrowserModule, AppRoutingModule, MatTableModule, MatSortModule],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

I have tried all the changes recommend like remove 'table' in the html, import MatDataSource but still nothing seem to correct this problem.  I am surprised this table does us ngFor for the data or am I using it wrong if I am pull the data from an API?

Thanks

Comment: which `@angular/material` version you're using?

Comment: Seems like import should be `import { MatTableModule } from '@angular/material/table';` and `import { MatSortModule } from '@angular/material/sort';
` instead of `import { MatTableModule, MatSortModule } from '@angular/material';
`

Comment: I am using 8.2.3 which is the reason I thought the import would be just '@angular/material'. Thanks

Comment: Can you please provide a stackblitz?

Comment: I always struggle with Stackblitz and installing dependencies.  It just always fails so I cannot re-create this to share sorry